# Why won't a textView from a different layout file not properly run setText but textViews from activity_main will?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-viewpager

The program is supposed to run getCurrentLocation and then set the textView "coordinates" to the value of the coordinates called. That text view is part of a pager view that draws from a separate .xml file than the main layout "activity_main".

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    CardAdapter CardAdapter;
    String coordinatesFinal;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    TextView coordinates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);
            }

        setupCardItems();

        ViewPager2 CardViewPager = findViewById(R.id.cardViewPager);
        CardViewPager.setAdapter(CardAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == 100 & grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            getCurrentLocation();
        }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public void getCurrentLocation()
        {
            coordinates = findViewById(R.id.coordinates);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService
                    (
                            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE
                    );
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            {
                fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(task ->
                {
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        coordinates.setText(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
                    }else
                        {
                            LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(10000).setFastestInterval(1000).setNumUpdates(1);
                            LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult)
                                {
                                    Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                    coordinatesFinal = location1.getLatitude()+", "+location1.getLongitude();
                                }
                            };

                            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        }
                });
            }else
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                }
        }


    //card view
    private void setupCardItems()
    {
        List<CardItem> CardItems = new ArrayList<>();

        CardItem itemPageOne = new CardItem();
        itemPageOne.setLocation("Home");
        itemPageOne.setTemp("60°f");
        itemPageOne.setWeatherDesc("Cloudy");
        itemPageOne.setWeatherIcon(R.drawable.cloud);
        itemPageOne.setHum("75%");
        itemPageOne.setVis("10");
        itemPageOne.setPrecip("50%");
        itemPageOne.setDew("40°f");
        itemPageOne.setCloud("80%");
        itemPageOne.setFog("75%");

        CardItem itemPageTwo = new CardItem();
        itemPageTwo.setLocation("Madison");
        itemPageTwo.setTemp("60°f");
        itemPageTwo.setWeatherDesc("Sunny");
        itemPageTwo.setWeatherIcon(R.drawable.sun);
        itemPageTwo.setHum("75%");
        itemPageTwo.setVis("10");
        itemPageTwo.setPrecip("50%");
        itemPageTwo.setDew("40°f");
        itemPageTwo.setCloud("80%");
        itemPageTwo.setFog("75%");

        CardItem itemPageThree = new CardItem();
        itemPageThree.setLocation("Milwaukee");
        itemPageThree.setTemp("60°f");
        itemPageThree.setWeatherDesc("Rainy");
        itemPageThree.setWeatherIcon(R.drawable.rain);
        itemPageThree.setHum("75%");
        itemPageThree.setVis("10");
        itemPageThree.setPrecip("50%");
        itemPageThree.setDew("40°f");
        itemPageThree.setCloud("80%");
        itemPageThree.setFog("75%");

        CardItems.add(itemPageOne);
        CardItems.add(itemPageTwo);
        CardItems.add(itemPageThree);

        CardAdapter = new CardAdapter(CardItems);
    }
}
```

I have narrowed it down to the line that doesn't work properly:

```js
coordinates.setText(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
```

I have tested the exact same line as above, only using a textView from inside activity main, which works just fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The file actually does crash, I mistakenly said it didn't, and I added both .xml Files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#566D8F"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsBar2"
            android:layout_width="27sp"
            android:layout_height="27sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70sp"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsBar"
            android:layout_width="27sp"
            android:layout_height="27sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginStart="70sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_handle"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/cardViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_container_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/pagerCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#EAC0A0"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coordinates"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temperature"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weatherDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOnboarding"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/humidity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Humidity"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/humVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/visibility"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingStart="15sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Visibility"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/visVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingRight="30sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/precipitation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Precip. "
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/precipVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dewPoint"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingStart="15sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Dew Point"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dewVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingRight="30sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cloud"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingLeft="30sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Cloud"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cloudVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fog"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:paddingStart="15sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:text="Fog"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fogVal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:paddingStart="10sp"
                        android:paddingTop="5sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="30sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 2: CardAdapter.java and CardItem.java

CardAdapter.java:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.cardViewHolder>
{
    private List<CardItem> CardItems;

    public CardAdapter(List<CardItem> CardItems) {
        this.CardItems = CardItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public cardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new cardViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_container_card, parent, false
                )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull cardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setCardData(CardItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CardItems.size();
    }

    class cardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView locationText;
        private TextView weatherDesc;
        private ImageView weatherIcon;
        private TextView tempVal;
        private TextView humVal;
        private TextView visVal;
        private TextView precipVal;
        private TextView dewVal;
        private TextView cloudVal;
        private TextView fogVal;

        public cardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            locationText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationName);
            weatherDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weatherDesc);
            weatherIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageOnboarding);
            tempVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
            humVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.humVal);
            visVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.visVal);
            precipVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.precipVal);
            dewVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dewVal);
            cloudVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cloudVal);
            fogVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fogVal);

        }

        void setCardData(CardItem CardItem)
        {
            locationText.setText(CardItem.getLocation());
            weatherDesc.setText(CardItem.getWeatherDesc());
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(CardItem.getWeatherIcon());
            tempVal.setText(CardItem.getTemp());
            humVal.setText(CardItem.getHum());
            visVal.setText(CardItem.getVis());
            precipVal.setText(CardItem.getPrecip());
            dewVal.setText(CardItem.getDew());
            cloudVal.setText(CardItem.getCloud());
            fogVal.setText(CardItem.getFog());
        }

    }
}
```

CardItem.java:

```
package com.example.viewpagertest;

public class CardItem
{
    private int weatherIcon;
    private String location;
    private String temp;
    private String weatherDesc;
    private String hum;
    private String vis;
    private String precip;
    private String dew;
    private String cloud;
    private String fog;


    //weather icon
    public int getWeatherIcon() {
        return weatherIcon;
    }

    public void setWeatherIcon(int weatherIcon) {
        this.weatherIcon = weatherIcon;
    }

    //location title
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    
    //temperature value
    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    //weather description
    public String getWeatherDesc() {
        return weatherDesc;
    }

    public void setWeatherDesc(String weatherDesc) {
        this.weatherDesc = weatherDesc;
    }

    //humidity value
    public String getHum() {
        return hum;
    }

    public void setHum(String hum) {
        this.hum = hum;
    }

    //visibility value
    public String getVis() {
        return vis;
    }

    public void setVis(String vis) {
        this.vis = vis;
    }

    //precipitation value
    public String getPrecip() {
        return precip;
    }

    public void setPrecip(String precip) {
        this.precip = precip;
    }

    //dew point value
    public String getDew() {
        return dew;
    }

    public void setDew(String dew) {
        this.dew = dew;
    }

    //cloud value
    public String getCloud() {
        return cloud;
    }

    public void setCloud(String cloud) {
        this.cloud = cloud;
    }

    //fog value
    public String getFog() {
        return fog;
    }

    public void setFog(String fog) {
        this.fog = fog;
    }
}
```

Here's the Console when running a debugger with the breakpoint at

```
coordinates.setText(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
```

The whole console breaks the character limit so here's a document with the console text.

[Console Text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AzBP2YuQ3Myuy-wH0_L9Eaifu7UJQwKo2p3ywPSXpxo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: show error log.

Comment: Sorry it isn't crashing just isn't setting the textView to anything. That doesn't happen when using a textView from in activity_main instead of the viewpager's xml file.

Comment: Rerun and set a breakpoint `coordinates.setText(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
` on this line, then post the information you get

Comment: If the TextView ist not in the main Layout you can't just use `findViewById`, you will have to use `cardViewPager.findViewById`. Butp please include both XML files so we can help

Comment: @Ferdinand Setting the breakpoint at that line causes a crash. Is there any other information should I post?

Comment: @Tobi I added both XML files in an edit. As for your suggestion to add "cardViewPager" to the front of the findViewById, should that instead be the name of the layout that the textView is in?

Comment: Your textview is not part of the MainActivity's xml file. Try setting it inside your adapter.

Comment: Yes it's supposed to crash, what information do you get on the android debugger ?

Comment: You have not shown the `CardAdapter` code so it is difficult to help.

Comment: Do share adapter code

Comment: @FletcherCrone, where do you inflate the `item_container_card.xml` layout ?

Comment: @Andrew I added all of the java files including CardAdapter

Comment: @PriyankaRajput I added CardAdapter.java just now

Comment: @Tobi Item_container_card.xml gets inflated in CardAdapter.java which I just added.

Comment: @Ferdinand I added the console when running the debugger with the specified breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if (location != null)
                {
                    // coordinates.setText(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
                    cardAdapter.setCoordinates(0 /*the cardItem number you want to update*/, location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
                }
```

Since the coordinates TextView is in your item xml, you will not be able to address it from the root of your MainActivity, but from your item.

---

**Update**
Thanks for adding the Adapter code:

Easiest would be to create a method in your adapter like the following:

```
setCoordinates(int position, String coords) {
    holders.get(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.coordinates).setText(coords);
}
```

To be able to access the holders on runtime, add the following:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.cardViewHolder>
{
    private List<CardItem> cardItems;
    private List<CardViewHolder> holders;
    ....

    @Override
    public cardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CardViewHolder holder = new cardViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_container_card, parent, false
            )
        );
        holders.add(holder);
        return holder;
    }
```

Another option would be to add the field `coordinates` to your `CardItem` and write the `setCoordinates` method like so:

```
setCoordinates(int position, String coords) {
    cardItems.get(position).setCoordinates(coords);
    notifyDataSetChanged();  // to reload the holders, only notifying the specific position will be faster to reload only the changed holder
}
```

Comment: How would I call the GPS coordinates from the method getCurrentLocation in MainActivity then?

Comment: @FletcherCrone in you MainActivity you only have to change the one line with `setText` to the line at the top of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the adapter items by creating a method in CardAdapter and calling it from main activity as below -

Create this method in your adapter class

```
public void updateAdapter(List<CardItem> CardItems) {
    this.CardItems = CardItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Replace below line

```
CardAdapter = new CardAdapter(CardItems);
```

With this one

```
CardAdapter.updateAdapter(CardItems);
```